# how to resolve smtp error : sending message?

Tags: asp.net, email, asp.net-web-api, smtp, smtpclient

Below is my code using smtp for sending mail.

```
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("user@gmail.com", "user@gmail.com");
mm.Subject = "test";
mm.Body = "hi";
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com",587);
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential { UserName = "user@gmail.com", Password = "" };
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Send(mm);
```

when  am trying to execute this code i got the below error,
[image: smtp error]

please help me to resolve this error..

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Below my code,                                                         MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("user@gmail.com", "user@gmail.com");
            mm.Subject = "test";
            mm.Body = "hi";
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com",587);
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential
            {
                UserName = "user@gmail.com",
                Password = ""
            };
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(mm);

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

- Check if the production server is blocked from making a connection: https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity
- Check if 2-Step verification is enabled, here: https://myaccount.google.com/security If it is not, and you don't want to/need to enable it, you need to allow the
  application 'less secure' access here: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps
- If you do want 2-Step verification, you have to generate a special app password and use that in the credentials. You can create this app password when you switch 2-Step verification on.

Comment: Its working perfectly!! Thank you so much..